# Reformatting JSON attributes when using Core Data and AFIncrementalStore

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, core-data, afincrementalstore

I have an iOS app quite similar to the one built here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app - i.e. **Core Data** and **AFIncrementalStore**, but with a custom Rails 3.1 server which serves JSON.

I have two problems of similar nature:

- Rails has an attribute named `id`, but this is a reserved word in Objective-C, so I'd like to rename it to `activityId` or similar in the iOS app. Where in the code should I perform this `id` -> `activityId` translation?
- All my date fields currently show up as `(null)` in the iOS app, which I suspect is due to Rails way of formatting dates (e.g. `"2012-09-14T11:32:09+02:00"`). Where in the iOS code should I add my own date parser?

I'd like to avoid custom JSON generation on the server side, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the "[Basic Example](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/tree/master/Examples)" from AFIncrementalStore's Github, I mapped Rails attributes to Core Data's at `attributesForRepresentation:ofEntity:fromResponse:`

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesForRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)representation
                                     ofEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity
                                 fromResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutablePropertyValues = [[super attributesForRepresentation:representation ofEntity:entity fromResponse:response] mutableCopy];
    if ([entity.name isEqualToString:@"Activity"]) {
        [mutablePropertyValues setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[representation valueForKey:@"id"] integerValue]] forKey:@"activityID"];
    }

    return mutablePropertyValues;
}
```

That said, I went down that path and learned later that it is not necessary because AFIS keeps that mapped for you. See [this deck](https://speakerdeck.com/mattt/afincrementalstore) under the section 'Augmented Managed Object Model'. [This podcast](https://soundcloud.com/mattt-thompson/syncing-with-afis) goes over it in detail.

As for the Date conversion, it is done in the same method above in the "[Twitter Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/tree/master/Examples/Twitter%20Client)" example:

```
[mutablePropertyValues setValue:[[NSValueTransformer valueTransformerForName:TTTISO8601DateTransformerName] reverseTransformedValue:[representation valueForKey:@"created_at"]] forKey:@"createdAt"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: GREAT, thank you! Now I'm getting somewhere! Note: there's a `setValue:` missing in the activityID example. I'm not getting the `TTTISO8601DateTransformer` to work, it spits out `nil` although format looks OK (`@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` in `TTTDateTransformers.m`). My debug output: `Import data: My first activity, 2012-09-14T11:00:00+02:00 -> (null)`

Comment: ...hmmm I think this is probably related to changes to `TransformerKit`, seems it's evolving recently: https://github.com/mattt/TransformerKit/commits/master

Comment: The `activityId` code above seems to work but spits out a `-[Activity activityId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xXXXXX` when I try to read activityId in `configureCell` - a quick googling reveals that many have "unrecognized selector" issues with Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing setValue: It got lost in the edits. I have similar code running with different attribute names so perhaps the error you are getting could be a mispelling of the attribute name? E.g. 'activityID' vs 'activityId'

Comment: Changing the data type of `activityID` from `NSInteger` to `int32_t` solved it! Now the date format issue remains; it's obviously some differences between the date format in the Twitter/App.net example (`2012-08-17T20:16:27Z`) and what my Rails app delivers (`2012-09-14T11:00:00+02:00`).

Comment: For fun, I tried the Twitter/App.net example and inserted a `NSLog(@"Import: %@, %@", [representation valueForKey:@"text"], [mutablePropertyValues objectForKey:@"createdAt"]);` *after* the `TTTISO8601DateTransformer` is used, and lo and behold: they also get `nil` values! I can't debug `TTTDateTransformers.m` properly because it doesn't seem that the *CocoaPods* files are recompiled when I build my project.

Comment: The date issue was solved when I used `reverseTransformedValue:` instead of `transformedValue:`.

Comment: Cool. I've updated the Date conversion code in the answer to the reverseTransformedValue: parameter.